# Python 3.4 googlemaps 'module' object not callable

Tags: python, google-maps, python-3.x

I'm new to programming Python and have been doing some tutorials which uses the code below. My code stumbles on the second line when i try and define the variable for the `googlemaps` module. The source code i got from an online tutorial is to obtain directions from the google maps server: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzkHU5GM8_E&list=PLHPcpp4e3JVqYgQFM9NPo_ksEqa_bRH79&t=74

```
from googlemaps import googlemaps

MS = googlemaps() <-- 'module' object is not callable
```

I have looked on the Python 3.4 documentation areas and the module areas. I have tried downloading the module again via PIPs but to no avail and Google hasn't brought up anything either.

I did notice that other codes have `GoogleMaps` (with capitals) which i have tried to call instead but it does not exist.
I have not tried the code in any other versions of Python but this seems like a very basic thing to go wrong.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: In youtube video it says mapservice = GoogleMaps(). Case is very important.

Comment: As i mentioned in my post, i did try and use the uppercase but it then throws an exception as `cannot import name GoogleMaps`

Answer (score 0):

The video is for a previous version of `googlemaps` library. In the latest version the API has been changed. If you want to install that (older) version:

```
pip install googlemaps==1.0.2
```

You should then write your import statement as exactly in the video (GoogleMaps).

Answer (score 0):

To get directions in the latest release you need to use `Client` and `direction`:

```
from googlemaps import Client

c = Client(key="api_key")

d = c.directions("texarkana","atlanta")
```

To get the steps as in the video:

```
steps = c.directions("texarkana","atlanta")[0]["legs"][0]["steps"]

for d in steps:
    print(d['html_instructions'])

Head <b>northeast</b> on <b>W 7th St</b> toward <b>Main St</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering Arkansas</div>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>US-71 S/Hickory St</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Continue to follow US-71 S</div>
Turn <b>right</b> onto the ramp to <b>Shreveport</b>
Merge onto <b>I-49 S</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering Louisiana</div>
Continue onto <b>Exit 215</b>
Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>LA-1 S/N Market St</b>
Turn <b>left</b> to merge onto <b>I-220 E</b> toward <b>Monroe</b>
Take exit <b>17B</b> on the <b>left</b> to merge onto <b>I-20 E</b> toward <b>Monroe</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering Mississippi</div>
Keep <b>right</b> at the fork to continue on <b>I-20 E/US 49 S</b>, follow signs for <b>Hattiesburg/Meridian</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Continue to follow I-20 E</div><div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering Alabama</div>
Take exit <b>106</b> for <b>I-459 N</b> toward <b>Atlanta/Montgomery</b>
Continue onto <b>I-459 N</b>
Take exit <b>29</b> toward <b>Atlanta</b>
Merge onto <b>I-20 E</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering Georgia</div>
Take exit <b>56B</b> for <b>Windsor St</b> toward <b>Spring St/Turner Field</b>
Slight <b>right</b> toward <b>Rawson St SW</b>
Continue onto <b>Rawson St SW</b>
Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Central Ave SW</b>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Memorial Dr SW</b>
Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Capitol Ave SW</b>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback but now the code stumbles at `c = client(key="api_key")` with the same error `'module' object not callable`. Do i need to obtain an api key before i can use this? the help page states you only require it for geocoding.

Comment: I could not get it to work until I activated it in developer settings. I used my app api key https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys